# CAML Query builder not working for And/Or combination in SharePoint 2010

Tags: caml

I am using CAML builder in SharePoint 2010 visual web part. But it is not working for **And/Or** combination.

Ex: I need to get the records from list based on **Status=published or (Status=Draft and createdBy=currently logged in user) and AppName=SharePoint**.

CAML query is not working for the above scenario. But for part of the above statement(below) is working.

**Status=published or (Status=Draft and createdBy=currently logged in user)**

Please let us know the solution which will work for And/Or combination in CAML query.

Thanks in Advance,
Krishna Rao Maturi.

Comment: As a sidenote, this library has helped me immensely when building CAML-queries: http://camlex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Work!!!

You may use 2 conditions only, to use more, you need use combination of conditions, example:

```
    <And>
         Condition A
         <or>
             Condition B
             Condition C
         <or>
    </And>
```

This equal this: (ConditionA && (ConditionB || ConditionC))